# PHP - How to clear tenacious Zend cache - tried 3 different methods all failed

Tags: php, caching, zend-framework

I was assigned a ticket at my workplace to remove a logo from one of our home pages. This particular application uses Zend on the backend. I inherited this code base, and the person who wrote it is out of office today. The project only uses 2 controllers.

I grepped the project and only found 1 instance of the logo in 1 phtml file. I removed the code which renders the logo, and the logo was still rendering after pushing to our master branch. I checked the files on the master branch and the code which renders the HTML is gone.

When I view page source on Chrome, the logo html is still present, so I am assuming the Zend cache is at work here. I first tried 1 of each of the following in the index controller only:

```
 $cache->clean(Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_OLD);
 $this->cache->clean();
 $cache->clean(Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL);
```

None worked individually, so I retried all 3 methods in both controllers (only 2 controllers). Still no change.

Any ideas on how to clear the cache? (or perhaps it is something else I am missing)

Comment: Hrm. I have a project in ZF1 that we've used `Bootstrap::clearCache();` for at least the last two years. Unfortunately, I couldn't tell you what we used before that.

Comment: Tried this and no effect...I need to speak with the person who coded this application